# Trouble sending a response string from my Express server to React front-end

Tags: reactjs, express, response, httpresponse

I want to reply to Fetch request with a URL in string format. Examples I've seen look fairly easy, but I believe my cors middleware may be messing something up.

Here is my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./database/db');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(require('./router.img.js'));
app.listen(4000, console.log('Listening on 4000'));

module.exports = app;
```

Here's where I send the response:

```
exports.postImage = (req, res) => {
  let sliceIndex = req.file.originalname.indexOf('.');
  let fileType = req.file.originalname.slice(sliceIndex);
  let url = "https://instaimages.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/" + 
  req.body.number + fileType;

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html'); 
  res.send(url);
};
```

I see a response on the front-end, but it does not contain the URL string. Here is what it looks like:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:4000/upload/", 
redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

Comment: why this `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')` .. you're sending a url not html ?

Comment: I am trying to send just the string, and that was recommended on similar question. When I remove it, I have the same response on the front end

Comment: Have you tried `text/plain`?

Comment: Just tried it, same response. I should note that the res.body comes back as a ReadableStream {locked: false}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
fetch('/your/api/endpoint')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => console.log(text));
```

`fetch` actually resolves to a `Response` object from which you need to do an additional step to extract the data you need. More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: YES, thank you so much. Looks like I need to read more of Fetch's docs, I could've sworn it was an issue with my server.